# ASP.NET MVC Keeping the controller light

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I've been told repeatedly to keep my controllers thin. Now I'm wondering if my controller is too thin?

Now my controllers are relying on exception's to relay errors from the BLL to the View. I'm not sure why this is wrong but something about it doesn't sit right.

I'll include some pseudo code below and hopefully someone can suggest a better method?

Any help would be much appreciated!

**My Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = KitchenRoles.Chefs)]
        public ActionResult Cook(PizzaVm pizzaVm, HttpPostedFileBase pictureFileBase)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                try
                {
                    BLL.Pizza.Cook(pizzaVm, pictureFileBase);
                }
                 catch (Exception ex) when (ex is PizzaBurntException || ex is NoOlivesException)
                {
                    @ViewBag.errormessage = ex.Message;
                    return View(pizzaVm);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) when (ex is PizzaNotFoundException)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("PizzaName", ex.message);

                    return View(pizzaVm);
                }
            }

            }
```

**My BLL.Pizza.Cook() Method:**

```
public static void Cook(PizzaVm pizzaVm, HttpPostedFileBase pictureFileBase)
        {

            if (!BLL.Pizza.NameExists(pizzaVm.name))
            {
                throw new PizzaNotFoundException("Pizza not found");
            }

            try
            {
                placeInOven(pizzaVm);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw new PizzaBurntException("It's burnt");
            }


        }
```

Comment: What we do is put all the business logic and grunt work in our api.  The our MVC Controllers simply do what your doing above.  But keep in mind there there may be times when its more appropriate to perform the tasks in the controller if it only applies to the site.  Our APIs are using by mobil apps, MVC Asp.Net sites, and even some windows forms apps.

Comment: thanks @loanburger any insight into relying on exceptions? Is this what you're doing on your site?

Comment: We do use exception and ModelSates as you do with the addition that we also log the exception in a DB for bug tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use exceptions for control flow. Exceptions should not be used to return a value from one layer(could be a method) to another to determine the cotntrol flow.Exceptions should be used to handle unexpected situations like a db error/ network error/code crashed due to unexpected things etc.

You can a simple POCO data strucutre to return a value form your methods/layers.

```
public class TransactionResult
{
  public bool IsSuccess {set;get;}
  public string Message {set;get;}
  public string ErrorCode {set;get;}
}
```

And you return an object of this from your method(s)/layers.

```
public TransactionResult Cook(PizzDto pizza)
{
   if (!BLL.Pizza.NameExists(pizza.name))
   {
     return new TransactionResult { ErrorCode= "NameExists"};
   }
   BLL.Pizza.KeepInOven(pizza);
   return new TransactionResult { IsSuccess = true };   
}
```

And whoever calling this will check the `IsSuccess` property of the return value and use that to determine the control flow.

This is just the basic solution to get started.You can improve this by adding a  generic T type Data property if you want to pass some data as well. Also you can create an eum for your errors and use that.

Now going back to your original question, Yes, do not put all your code in the controller action methods. **It is not just the controller you should keep thin, but every class / layer as possible.** Do not forget the single responsibility principle :)